# How to edit font color in woocommerce checkout page

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, divi

Im trying to modify the h3, body and cart detail's font color on my check-out page, I had it right before but this line seems to be overriding my previous style. [This is what im trying to achieve](https://ibb.co/DVDzRFV)

https://intiwallets.com/checkout/

```
.et_pb_bg_layout_dark, .et_pb_bg_layout_dark h1, .et_pb_bg_layout_dark h2, .et_pb_bg_layout_dark h3, .et_pb_bg_layout_dark h4, .et_pb_bg_layout_dark h5, .et_pb_bg_layout_dark h6 {
   color:#FFF !important;
}
```

If I un-check that my regular styles show up correctly. [Print](https://ibb.co/422Xq5y)

I tried these lines to fix it but it did not solve the issue as the order details are still showing up in white, same as the credit card gateway label. [Print](https://ibb.co/fSXNpjb)

```
div.woocommerce h3 {
    color:#222222!important;
}

div.woocommerce p {
    color:#404040
}

li.wc_payment_method.payment_method_wocommerce_yape_peru, li.wc_payment_method.payment_method_bank_transfer_1, 
li.wc_payment_method.payment_method_bank_transfer_2, 
li.wc_payment_method.payment_method_bank_transfer_3 {
  color: #404040!important;  
}
```

Also tried this, but it overrode all my other pages settings.

```
.et_pb_bg_layout_dark
{
color: #404040!important
    }
```

Thank you in advance, any feedback would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why not changing it via Divi settings? If you use the designer for the checkout you should continue using it in this case.

Comment: Forgot to mention that changing the settings on the divi builder does not seem to work, it even shows correctly on the builder view [link] (https://ibb.co/WWCv1GJ), the first line of code I posted seems to be overwriting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed the issue.

```css
div.woocommerce-checkout-review-order {
color: #404040!important
}

div.woocommerce h3 {
    color:#222222!important;
}

div.woocommerce p {
    color:#404040
}
```